# How to update my flash file in firefox

Tags: flash, firefox

I have updated the flash file on my page.
In IE its showing the latest one.
But in firefox the previous file only reflecting...

Any other plugins for java, flash should I download for firefox?

Answer (score 0):

ctrl-f5?

clear your cache? (under the preferences menu somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

You can always put a param (?somevalue) at the end of the .swf file location where you're calling it into your page.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the flash file itself, clear your cache. (Tools > Clear Recent History > Cache) (Or Ctrl+D).

To clear settings the flash file may have saved to your machine (LSO files), install the BetterPrivacy plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6623/

Answer (score 0):

And some extra parameters to the embedded code inside you html.

```
For ex:   myFlashFile.swf?ver=1.1
```

This will make the browser think is a different file and reload it from server.

You cannot ask the visitors to clear the cache. This workaround will ensure you that the visitors will always see the latest version of the swf and not a cached one.

Also if you continue to update to swf then just keep changing the param to a new value.

At the next update it can look like :      `myFlashFile.swf?ver=1.2`